# Get Path of process under different user

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I'm writing a program that checks processes (when they start), and kills any processes that aren't acceptable.

My program is mostly done, but I only just ran into a problem: when I try to get the path (one of the criteria) of a process running under a different user, (MainModule.FileName) I get an exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception occurred
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Message="Access is denied"
  NativeErrorCode=5
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)    at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)    at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()    at Forcep.Logic.ProcessStarted(Object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) in J:\Variable\Programming\Forcep\Forcep\Logic.vb:line 126
```

Now, the program doing the checking is running with complete administrator privileges, so I can pretty much wrangle any permission I need.

How can I obtain the path of the process? (I can use WMI, by the way, I've already used it for another part of this).

Comment: Could you show the code you are using, and any OS details about where it runs (server, xp, win7, etc)?

Comment: I use Process.MainModule.FileName - The process works fine to do other stuff. This is running on a domain-joined XP machine, under a user who is local to the machine. The filename is to be found for a process that is being run by a user who IS on the domain, not the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have a client app running under the user in question, and using that client app to query the path etc.

Answer (score 0):

> program doing the checking is running with complete administrator privileges

I assume that you mean "elevated administrator" on Vista or Windows 7 with UAC enabled, accomplished by right-clicking on the executable and choosing "Run as administrator".

I tried this on my Windows 7 system and the only process that failed this way for `MainModule` was `audiodg`. I think this process is protected to ensure the security of digital rights for audio. You should catch this exception if you are looping through all processes.

(If this doesn't answer your question, consider using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to examine the process that is giving you trouble. Right-click on Process Explorer to run it elevated. Bring up the properties for the process, and hit Security tab, Permissions button. Compare the access control list with a process that you are able to successfully query.)

Comment: I found the issue happened to be that it was attempting to access process paths in another userspace, with that user being from another domain. I mentioned this in the above comment.